# Show modal after every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I want my modal to show as a popup after every 5 seconds without triggering the button, but I am unable to do it.
I used jquery function show and setTimeout but it works only the first time the page is loaded

This is my jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

My Modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I want it to open after every 5 seconds
Please help

Comment: use `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks it worked!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
setInterval(function () {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 5000);
```

The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval` and `5000` as 2000 is 2 seconds.

`setInterval` is "repeat this function every N miliseconds". 
`setTimeout` is "execute this function once after N miliseconds"

```js
setInterval(function () {
  console.log('Modal.show()');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with recursive `setTimeout` instead `setInterval` because the `setTimeout` schedules ensure the next call right at the end of the current one.

The recursive `setTimeout` is a more flexible method than setInterval. This way the next call may be scheduled differently, depending on the results of the current one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function showModal() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      setTimeout(showModal, 5000);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 5000 inside setInterval instead of 2000 since 5000 is 5 seconds